# WebSecurity.CreateAccount fails for MySQL

Tags: mysql, security, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix and stuck at the first place while trying to create users in MySQL database.

The error message is in line:

```
var token = WebSecurity.CreateAccount(email, password, requireEmailConfirmation);
```

Error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([Email]) = 'TE3ST@TEST.DE')'

I can fully understand that the server is trying to use SQL formatted query to MySQL server. How do I recompile or tell the `WebSecurity.CreateAccount` to use MySQL formatted queries?

Any idea?

Thank you in advance
krish

Answer (score 2):

The WebSecurity helper is a wrapper around the SimpleMembership Provider which doesn't support MySQL (at the moment, at least). It only supports SQL Server and SQL Compact 4.0. You can write your own membership provider which inherits [ExtendedMembershipProvider](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1b78397f32fc#src/WebMatrix.WebData/ExtendedMembershipProvider.cs) if you need MySQL support.

Comment: Hi, thank you.. I have created a project in visual studio 2012 using MySQL connector 6.6.5 and followed this steps. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117157/Setting-up-MySql-Membership-with-Visual-Studio-201

somehow now it works fine. I didn't hard code anything just used the template VS2012 had to offer. Hope this helps someone

Comment: It works because you are not using the WebSecurity helper. You are using a Membership Provider that is designed to work specifically with MySQL.