# Update Row in Table on Database for Each New User WebMatrix

Tags: mysql, webmatrix

I have a table (About_User) in my database (StarterSite) that is supposed to work so that each seperate row is for each seperate user. However, no matter which user is signed in, they all have access to the same row (in other words new rows aren't being created for each new user). I have triple checked to make sure everything in my database was set up correctly. I am using the StarterSite template with this Registration page (edited for question):

```
// If all information is valid, create a new account
    if (Validation.IsValid()) {
        // Insert a new user into the database
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");

        // Check if user already exists
        var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);
        if (user == null) {
            // Insert email into the profile table
            db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email) VALUES (@0)", email);

            // Create and associate a new entry in the membership database.
            // If successful, continue processing the request
            try {
                bool requireEmailConfirmation = !WebMail.SmtpServer.IsEmpty();
                var token = WebSecurity.CreateAccount(email, password, requireEmailConfirmation);
                if (requireEmailConfirmation) {
                    var hostUrl = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);
                    var confirmationUrl = hostUrl + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Account/Confirm?confirmationCode=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token));

                    WebMail.Send(
                        to: email,
                        subject: "Please confirm your account",
                        body: "Your confirmation code is: " + token + ". Visit <a href=\"" + confirmationUrl + "\">" + confirmationUrl + "</a> to activate your account."
                    );
                }

                if (requireEmailConfirmation) {
                    // Thank the user for registering and let them know an email is on its way
                    Response.Redirect("~/Account/Thanks");
                } else {
                    // Navigate back to the homepage and exit
                    WebSecurity.Login(email, password);

                    Response.Redirect("~/");
                }
            } catch (System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateUserException e) {
                ModelState.AddFormError(e.Message);
            }
        } else {
            // User already exists
            ModelState.AddFormError("Email address is already in use.");
        }
    }
```

The table does have an ID column that (should) autoincrement.

The other columns are from a form that collects different information from the user like an 'About Me' page and therefore should be different for each person.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some things in your question that I don't understand. First of all your code doesn't look edited (it is the same as the template from row 39 to row 82). Second, your question has the mysql tag: if you are using a MySql database instead of the Sql Ce database of the Starter Site template, maybe this could be the problem (look at [WebSecurity.CreateAccount fails for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770637/websecurity-createaccount-fails-for-mysql)).

With the default StarteSite Sql Ce database the answer to your question is quite simple. Add the following row

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO About_User(UserId, UserPage) VALUES (@0, @1)", 
    db.GetLastInsertId(), userPage);
```

just after the `db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email) VALUES (@0)", email);` statement.

There is no need of an ID autoincrement column in your About_User table, but only of a UserId Primary Key column as foreing key.